# Cisco IOS XE DHCP Starlink - Static route issue

Tags: cisco, routing

Today i connected the Starlink dish to an Cisco ISO-XE Box (ISR1111) as a secondary wan link and noticed some strange behavior.

I installed a static host-Route to an VPN Tunnel endpoint via

```
ip route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.255 dhcp
```

which works fine.
The Route to the destination network is installed in the routing table with Starlinks CGN IP 100.127.something.something Next-Hop.
Due to our Coverage is not stable it sometimes happen that Dishy is loosing Satellite connection and the routes including the implicit DHCP default-route are deleted. After the Connection is back the default route is reinstalled, but the static configured host routes are not.

```
Router#sh ip route 9.9.9.9
Routing entry for 9.9.9.9/32
  Known via "static", distance 1, metric 0
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 100.127.255.3
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
```

"deb ip routing" shows:

```
*Sep  2 19:09:01.179: RT: del 9.9.9.9 via 100.127.255.3, static metric [1/0]
*Sep  2 19:09:01.180: RT: delete subnet route to 9.9.9.9/32
*Sep  2 19:09:01.180: RT: updating static 0.0.0.0/0 (0x0) [local lbl/ctx:1048577/0x0] omp-tag:0  :
    via 0.0.0.0 Tu1  0 1048578 0x100001

*Sep  2 19:09:01.180: RT: updating static 0.0.0.0/0 (0x0) [local lbl/ctx:1048577/0x0] omp-tag:0  :
    via 100.127.255.3   0 1048578 0x100001

*Sep  2 19:09:01.180: RT: rib update return code: 17
```

At first i supposed some sort of Bug, but even after trying several IOS Versions the issue is still the same. Any ideas here?

Comment: Yes, bug. Notify TAC. It might be fixed in a few years. (there are *lots* of bugs tied to DHCP addressing.)

Comment: Is there any change in behaviour if you include the intended egress interface, as in `ip route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.255 <egressIF> dhcp` ?

Comment: there is no change in this behavior when binding the Route to a Interface or not. I'm wondering why i stumple upon this "bug" just with Starlink's DHCP, i have several quite similar configurations that are running fine for years.

Comment: After reading your question multiple times, there seem to be a couple ways to understand the question. Can you add clarity? Sounds like there is a private WAN circuit as primary, but satellite internet as backup? Can we assume private circuit is statically addressed and satellite is DHCP? Does Dishy=Starlink?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score -1):

Configure Static route within including the CE interface of the ISR1100

ip route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.255 Gi0/0 dhcp